# Cloudfront URL rewriting/remapping so content has two URLs?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm managing a documentation website that has URLs in this pattern:

```
/product-foo/1.2.3/user-guide/system-requirements.html
```

I want to have **two** URLs to the page:

```
/product-foo/1.2.3/user-guide/system-requirements.html  
/product-foo/latest/user-guide/system-requirements.html
```

as can be done with an Apache Web server as documented at
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

> "Assume we have recently renamed the page `foo.html` to `bar.html` and now want to provide the old URL for backward compatibility. However, we want that users of the old URL even not recognize that the pages was renamed - that is, we don't want the address to change in their browser.
>   **Solution:** We rewrite the old URL to the new one internally via the following rule:
>       `RewriteEngine  on`
>       `RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT]"`

The idea is that with each new product version, I'll update the redirects to point the "latest" pattern to the documentation for the most recently released version. This is so people can link to the latest documentation if they want or they can link to a version-specific version if they want.

Can this be done with Cloudfront *configuration*? Can it be done with s3 alone without Cloudfront? Can it be done with AWS Lambda or Lambda@Edge? (Will the solution be subject to the Lambda@Edge bandwith limits?) Can you provide a specific example solution?

Comment: *"Will the solution be subject to the Lambda@Edge bandwith limits?"*  Lambda@Edge doesn't have "bandwidth limits."  Are you referring to generated response size limits?  How many products are involved?  This is relevant because your proposed scenario can be achieved, but of course would require a mapping table so that the logic would know what the "latest" version of each product is... and, arguably, the "latest" link should redirect to the current page rather than being an alternate URL.  That would be a different solution than essentially aliasing one path to another.  Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Yes, generated response size limits. We have 11 products but are expecting more. Even with expected increases, a dozen or a couple dozen items in a look-up table seems do-able. We do not want a simple redirect because we want most people to link to the latest documentation and have their links continue to point to the latest documentation unless they explicitly reference a particular version. A simple redirect changes the URL in the browser so most visitors would never know about the "latest" URL format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done using a Lambda@Edge trigger.  The generated response size limits of Lambda@Edge do not apply unless the Lambda function, itself, is actually *generating* the response by populating the `body` attribute of the response object with content it has created or obtained somewhere else, thus *generating* the response within the function.

With an Origin Request trigger:

- the trigger fires only after the cache is checked, and only when there *not* a cache hit (with a cache hit, the origin isn't contacted, so invoking the trigger isn't needed)
- the trigger fires before the request is sent to the origin
- you can modify the path that will be sent in the request to the origin
- the response is cached under the path originally requested by the browser, not the modified path
- the browser is not redirected, so the address bar does not change.¹

Fundamentally, all we need to do in the Lambda function is extract the request object, modify the URI² and tell CloudFront to continue processing the request, as modified.  We're just rewriting part of the request in flight, and returning control to CloudFront.

The example, below, is almost certainly not the most optimal or tidy way to handle a series of possible string manipulations, but is adequate to illustrate the general idea of what your code needs to accomplish, by whatever mapping and matching mechanism you want to use.

You could statically remap the values, or you could use any number of database strategies to look up the original path and find the correct, current destination to use.

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    request.uri = request.uri
        .replace(/^\/product-foo\/latest\//,'/product-foo/1.0.0/')
        .replace(/^\/product-bar\/latest\//,'/product-bar/3.2.1/')
        .replace(/^\/product-three\/latest\//,'/product-three/5.5.5/');

    return callback(null, request);
};
```

`event.Records` is always an array of exactly one member, and `event.Records[0].cf` contains all of the relevant information for this particular invocation.  `event.Records[0].cf.request` is the original request.  Modifying this object and supplying it as the second argument to the callback directs CloudFront to continue normal processing, using the modified request.

The first argument to the callback is always `null`, indicating that no exception occurred.  If an exception is thrown, or the first argument otherwise isn't `null`, then CloudFront returns a generic error to the viewer... it does not display the exception, since that could contain a stack trace or other sensitive informarion that should not be exposed.  The error is accessible in the Lambda logs.

---

¹unless, of course, the origin server actually responds with a redirect.

²what Lambda@Edge calls the "URI" is actually only the path.  The complete URI is technically path + '?' + query string, but Lambda@Edge separates these two things.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Double thanks for providing source code. I will be investigating this over the next couple days. I see the request URL is being changed so I'll be watching to assure the URL in the browser doesn't change. However, at first glance this looks like exactly what I was after.

Comment: `request.uri` is the path that CloudFront sends to the origin server, here.  It definitely should not change what's in the browser's address bar... unless for any reason your origin server generates a subsequent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in lot of ways.

You can point to the object in s3 bucket with the new name.

With the pattern in cloudfront, if nothing matches to your pattern you can send it to a lambda with API Gateway where you can configure where to go the new file with a redirect. You can receive the error path as a path parameter to lambda. You can maintain the configuration in a s3 location or dynamo or on any desired storage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Attaching the lambda to the error handler is an unexpected solution. I'm reluctant to manage expected behavior in error-handling code. I want an appropriate HTTP response code: 200 possibly 302. But I am not opposed to trying this. Can you provide explicit info, sample code or a pointer to documentation that describes capturing a fail-to-match-bucket-item request? I should be explicit: our content is statically served from S3 so the configuration needs to be part of the S3 delivery configuration, not a separate EC2 server or some such.